# htaccess rewrite - take last element of certain query string and put it into center of new url

Tags: .htaccess, url-rewriting, query-string

I would like to rewrite all urls who look like this:

test-domain.com/folderX/part-two/37-**elementX**
to
test-domain.com/certain-**elementX**-special-group

---

- the number to the left of the element can be different
  for each different element
- and the number can be stripped away

---

More examples:

test-domain.com/folderX/part-two/21-**elementY**
to
test-domain.com/certain-**elementY**-special-group

Answer (score 0):

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^.*-([^-]*)$ /certain-$1-special-group
```

Will map both

```
test-domain.com/folderX/part-two/21-element
test-domain.com/folderX/part-two/37-element
```

to

```
test-domain.com/certain-element-special-group
```

(You can test this here: http://htaccess.madewithlove.be/)

If you want to match specifically against a prefix of:

```
test-domain.com/folderX/part-two
```

Then you could use:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^[^/]+/folderX/part-two/[\d]+-([^-]*)$ /certain-$1-special-group
```

(You can also test this here: http://htaccess.madewithlove.be/)

Comment: The problem is that it also works with `test-domain.com/begin-end` ->  `test-domain.com/certain-end-special-group`

Comment: I tried this and got an "internal server error 500".

Comment: ( and the "folderX/part-two/" could be used to identify the query-string... )
But thank you four trying !

Comment: I've edited based on your feedback @user2103255.  It would be helpful if you also give some examples of what you _wouldn't_ want it to match (assuming I haven't now guessed correctly).

Answer (score 0):

You can use:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^[^/]+/[^/]+/\d+-([^-]+)$ /certain-$1-special-group [R=301,L]
```

Only for URL like: /folder/folder/[nnn]-[name without -]

And to avoid any conflict with an other existing file or directory, add after `RewriteEngine on`:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
```

Comment: I tried this, but it didn´t do anything.
( and the "folderX/part-two/" should be used to identify )
But thank you for taking the time to try!

Comment: I change flags, to make it more visible